# Scoping callbacks in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, callback, scope

I have an invitation system where a user can get an invitation in one of two ways - from the **site** (i.e., they find us without an invitation) or from a `current_user`.

If the invitation comes from a `current_user`, then the `invitation.sender_id` is set to `current_user.id`.  If the invitation comes from the site, the `invitation.sender_id` is set to "0" (integer).

LOGIC:

1. A `current_user` can send multiple invitations, but can only send an invitation to a unique email address once.
2. A site visitor can request an invitation be sent to their email address, but only if they have not personally requested an invitation before.
3. The `before_create` callback in model - `invitation.rb` should check the scope of the invitation request, and validate for `unique = true` only in the context of the `invitation.sender_id`.
4. An email can reside multiple times in the Invitations Table, but not under the same sender_id.

I have tried to find a solution here on Stack and elsewhere, but I can't find anything that provides a solution.

How do I limit the `before_create` callback scope to the `invitation.sender_id`?

**EDIT**

I think what I have to do is separate the callback into 2...

```
before_create :recipient_has_no_requested_invitation
before_create :sender_has_not_invited_recipient, :if => :sender

def recipient_has_no_requested_invitation
  if Invitation.exists?(sender_id: 0, recipient_email: :recipient_email)
    errors.add :recipient_email, 'An invitation has already been sent to that email address.'
  end
end

def sender_has_not_invited_recipient
  if Invitation.exists?(sender_id: :current_user, recipient_email: :recipient_email)
    errors.add :recipient_email, 'You have already sent an invitation to that person.'
  end
end
```

This code looks good, but the callbacks are returning 'true' instead of 'false', and allowing the record to be saved.  Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting the callback into 2 didn't solve the problem.  First of all, my logic was reversed.  It expects it to return false, but the way the callback is written, it returns true.

I fiddled with this and a similar case for a week, before I settled on this:

```
validates :[attribute_name], uniqueness: { scope: :attribute_name }
```

for example:

```
validates :recipient_email, uniqueness: { scope: :sender_id }
```

You can append other `{options}` to the chain if you need to.